# What does "Uniquely defined up to a set of measure 0" mean?

Tags: measure-theory, partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces, weak-derivatives

***(Uniqueness of Weak Derivatives)***

A weak derivative of $u$, if exists, is **uniquely defined up to a set of measure zero**.

Special case proof (improvise from a book):

Let $v$ and $w$ be weak $1^{th}$-partial derivatives of $u(x,t)$ on a compact interval $U=[0,1]$, then
$$ \int_{0}^{1} u \phi_{x} \: dx = - \int_{0}^{1} v \phi \: dx $$
and
$$ \int_{0}^{1} u \phi_{x} \: dx = - \int_{0}^{1} w \phi \: dx $$
where $\phi$ is also in $C^{1}(U)$ with compact support in $U$. Then we must aslo have $v(x,t) = w(x,t)$.

---

I absolutely understood the proof but what does it mean that a weak derivative is **uniquely defined up to a set of measure zero**?

I found a similar question with an accepted answer here: [What is set of measure zero?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/620415/what-is-set-of-measure-zero). But no idea the connection to the proof above.

Comment: It means that if $v,w$ are both weak derivatives of $u$, then the set of points  where $v\neq w$ has measure zero.

Comment: Are you familiar with the Lebesgue measure?

Comment: @CalvinKhor but that is not indicated in the proof. And if the function $u$ is differentiable then the weak derivative = the "strong" derivative right?

Comment: The proof uses the so called 'fundamental theorem of the calculus of variations'. This theorem only gives you uniqueness up to a null set. So you can only get uniqueness up to a null set. (unless you know something extra) And if the function $u$ is differentiable then the weak derivative is equal to the strong derivative, **again up to a null set**. If you are not familiar with this then you should read up on some measure theory

Comment: Suppose that you defined some other function $\psi(x) = \phi_x(x)$ except that a single value was modified, e.g., $\psi(1/2) = 100$ or something. What this is saying is that since we only ever integrate $\phi_x$, we don't really care about the fact that it differs from $\psi$ at a single point, as their integral against test functions will be the same. Why this is true is technical and requires some measure theory as the other comments say, but the reason why it is useful is that we can loosen our notions of what it means for two functions to be equal to make our lives easier